# UIButton's image wont change correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIButton which I change its image twice.

Both changes work, but only if one is executed.

e.g. The first statement changes the image and it can be seen, but only if the second statement is not run. If I run both statements only the last image change can be seen.

It seems to skip the first image change.

These executions run in a timer and I have a slight delay on the second image change, hoping to avoid this problem.

Even if I change the delay, to what seems like enough time to see the image change, there is no visual change.

How can I avoid this issue and change the UIButtons image twice, making both changes visible?

EDIT ->

```
[A1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fileString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            
[self performSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:) withObject:A1 withObject:fileString2];
```

I call these methods

```
 -(void) changeImage: (UIButton *) button withString: (NSString *) string
 {
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

 -(void) startInvocation: (UIButton *) button withString: (NSString *) string
 {
     NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                            [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:)]];
     [invocation setTarget:self];
     [invocation setSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:)];
     [invocation setArgument:button atIndex:2];
     [invocation setArgument:string atIndex:3];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.15f invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: when using an NSInvocation, you need to take the address of the arguments you give to setArgument. it should be `setArgument:&button` and `setArgument:&string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the image twice in the same event loop, only the second image will be seen.  Set the first image then start a NSTimer and program the event to set the second image.  You should see the change.

```
-(void)switchImage {
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dai00003.jpg"];    
}

-(IBAction) run {
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dai00001.jpg"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(switchImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: I change the image using a normal setImage statement. I then use an NSInvocation with a delay to set the image a second time. This invocation uses a timer. How would I do it otherwise?

Comment: Thanks. do I pass arguments to e.g. switchImage using userInfo in the selector?

Comment: Not exactly : check the doc !

Comment: I read it, it isnt clear. How are arguments for a method passed to this statement? or isnt it supported?

Comment: I mean, this method works as you say, but it needs to be hard-coded?

Comment: or use another class member to carry your arguments.  Cheers